# Exemplo de requisição com delphi

Tags: delphi, rest, restful

Preciso consumir uma rest api que retorna json.

O sistema foi feito com Delphi, estou usando a ide delphi xe7, nunca fiz requisões pra consumir api em sistemas pra desktop, tendo isso como base por onde começo?

Olha ai o sistema
[image: sistema em delphi]

**RESOLUÇÃO**
http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com/2013/07/lendo-dados-json-em-aplicacoes-delphi.html

Comment: Primeiro tens que ter o link para começar a consumir os dados, tipo de autenticação, filtragem de dados e com o retorno vai ter acesso ao JSON, teria que tratar e alimentar o seu sistema desktop. Pelo menos foi isso que eu entendi, se tiver mais informações teria que especificar melhor na pergunta.

Comment: sim, tenho a api tudo certinho e as rotas funcionando.
Vi q na propria ide do delphi tem os componentes restClient ...request e response. com eles consigo me conectar com a api usando a urlBase, agora quero pegar e mandar json e formatar pra exibir no sistema

Comment: Já que você tem o JSON, agora é só tratar ele para visualizar no sistema. Aqui nesse link um exemplo, de como ler dados JSON http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com/2013/07/lendo-dados-json-em-aplicacoes-delphi.html e na documentação da embarcadero http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/JSON. O que iria te ajudar tbm, é o Postman, assim você consegue ver a estrutura que está retornando.

Comment: vlw, isso ja ajudou.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, você pode usar o RESTRequest4Delphi para consumir a API:
https://github.com/viniciussanchez/RESTRequest4Delphi

Bastaria fazer isso aqui:

```
begin
  TRequest.New.BaseURL('http://localhost:8888/users')
    .Accept('application/json')
    .Get;
end;
```

Você também pode usar os componentes nativos TRESTRequest, TRESTResponse e TRESTClient para consumir, ou então o TIdHTTP